# How to get owner and full path of 50 large size file across all users?

Tags: shell, shell-script

Below command list top 50 files regardless of subfolders.

```
$ls -lR /root/home | sort +4 -5nr | head -50
```

Current Result:

```
-rw-r--r--    1 john   dpst      192954384 Nov  7 07:36 filenxx1.gz
-rw-rw----    1 paul   dpst      192188934 Nov 18 10:10 filenyyy1.mov
```

My new requirement is to get its "owner" and its "full path"

Expecting Result:

```
john  /home/dev/proj/filenxx1.gz
paul  /home/dev/proj/filenyyy1.mov
```

Please help me how to loop the list of 50 files and to get is owner and full path using "find" or any command in unix.

Comment: Can you confirm that by "top 50 files" you mean "50 largest files", as opposed to "50 most popular files" or something else? Just "top 50" is not clearn.

Comment: What are you sorting on ?

Comment: 50 large size file across all users

Comment: @Jidder - I am new to this forums. why all your reply gone. I am not able to view it...

Comment: @NageshwaranM I deleted my answer whilst i work out why it's not working :)

Comment: @Jitter - Any luck why it is giving different result. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
find /root/home -printf "%s\t%u\t%p\n" | sort -rn | head -50 | cut -f2-
```

The `find` oututs the size, owner, and full path, then the `cut` removes the first field which you didn't want.

Comment: The abouve command return error ###$find: bad option -printf